# Formalizing picking the nth element of each row of a matrix, being n determined by a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've struggled so far to formalize the following in mathematical notation.

Let $h_{i}$ be a variable containing a natural number between 1 and n. Let S be the following matrix of size $m x n$

$$
S = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
s_{11} & \cdots & s_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
s_{i1} & \cdots & s_{in}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I would like to be able to formalize the following mathematically. For each row of the matrix, I want to pick the $n^{th}$ element, being this element determined by vector $\vec h$.

In other words. Let's assume the following.

$$
h=[3,2,1]
$$

$$
S=
\begin{pmatrix} 
4 & 3 & 5 \\
2 & 9 & 7 \\ 
5 & 8 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I would like to end up with the following vector $\vec z$

$$
z = [5, 9, 5]
$$

In the first row I pick the third element ($h_{1}=3$). In the second row I pick the second element ($h_{2}=2$), and I pick the first in the last ($h_{3}=1$).

As I've said I would like to formalize this mathematically, any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you assume your matrix is a square matrix as in the example? If so the last row of the general version of $S$ should start with $s_{n1}$  since it's row $n.$

Comment: No, just thought it would be better understood with the example. The matrix does not need to be a square matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are typos in your S matrix, the lower left entry should be $S_{m1}$, not $S_{i1}$ and the lower right should be $S_{mn}$ not $S_{in}$. Let $$S=\left(\begin{matrix}S_{11}&S_{12}&...&S_{1n}\\S_{21}&S_{22}&...&S_{2n}\\
...&&...&\\S_{m1}&S_{m2}&...&S_{mn}\end{matrix}\right), h=\left(\begin{matrix}h_1\\h_2\\...\\h_m\end{matrix}\right)$$

Then z with $z_i=S_{i h_i}$ for $i=1,2,...,m$ chooses the "ith entry of h"th element of the ith row of S and puts it in the ith entry of z. That is,

$$z=\left(\begin{matrix}S_{1h_1}\\S_{2h_2}\\...\\S_{mh_m}\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Yep. Is that a problem?